# Trouble creating a method to reverse an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having a problem trying to reverse an arraylist using a for loop. This is what I did, but it doesn't reverse the array:

```
import java.util.*;                                                          

class Test {                                                                 
    public static void main(String[] args) {                                 
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();                  
        list.add(3);                                                         
        list.add(4);                                                         
        list.add(5);                                                         
        reverse(list);                                                       
    }                                                                        
    public static void reverse(ArrayList<Integer> list){                     
        Integer [] reverse = new Integer[list.size()];                       
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){                                   
            reverse[i] = list.get(0);                                        
            System.out.println (reverse[i]);                                 
        }                                                                    
    }                                                                        
}
```

This is the output I expected:

```
5
4
3
```

While this is what I'm getting:

```
$ java Test
3
3
3
```

Comment: `list.get(0);` - you're getting the same element each time. Even if you corrected that, it would still only copy the elements in the same order.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the loop? or are you trying to print out the loop in reverse?

Comment: no i was trying to reverse the elements in the array list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void reverse(ArrayList<Integer> list){
        Integer [] reverse = new Integer[list.size()];
        for (int i=list.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
            reverse[i]= list.get(i);

            System.out.println (reverse[i]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the values in reverse order (which is what it looks like you are doing):

```
public static void reverse(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    for (int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){  
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

If you want to return the reversed list in an array:

```
public static Integer[] reverse(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    Integer[] reverse = new Integer[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        reverse[i] = list.get(list.size()-1-i);
        System.out.println(reverse[i]);
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly getting the first item in the `list`, assigning it to a new element in the array, and printing it.  The `get` method doesn't remove the item from the list; it just returns it.

Calculate the index from the end of the list, then call `get`.

```
reverse[i] = list.get(list.size() - i - 1);
```

But since you're just printing the value from the array as soon as you assign it to the array, the array is useless.  You just need to print the value from the calculated index.

```
System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - i - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this:

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

As for your method, you were assigning the value at list(0) to every index in your array. This will reverse your list in place, without using as much extra memory.

```
public static void reverse(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    if (list == null) return;
    int n = list.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() / 2; i++) {
        int tmp = list.get(i);
        list.set(i, list.get(n - 1 - i));
        list.set(n - 1 - i, tmp);
    }
}
```